# Standard to let user select duration for hours and minutes

Tags: forms, time, datetimepicker, duration

I'm working on an app and I need to find a solution that lets users select a time duration for **hours** and **minutes**. (Example Form: "How long will you need to archive this?" Selection by user: 2 hours | 20 Minutes)
Is there a standard component for this? 
I only found a picker for dates and clocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tom, how granular does this setting have to be?

Especially for less technically savvy users, providing a set of meaningful presets could already do the trick. E.g., here's the menu for setting the alert for a calendar event (taken from Fantastical for Mac):

[image]

If you click <kbd>Custom…</kbd>, you get to see this:

[image]

If that doesn't work, you could simply concatenate static text with either free-form text fields or popup menus, something like this:

`Archive for [number] hours and [number] minutes`

Note, though, that the error handling for free-form text fields can be annoying, because `2 hours and 65 minutes` wouldn't sense. :)

Finally, a quick tip: unless this violates existing styles in your application, consider avoiding verbose questions such as "How long will you need to archive this?" They typically make scanning a set of similar questions more tedious, because the first few words per question usually aren't different enough.

Instead, keep it more concise, as mentioned above: "Archive for…"

Good luck!